# SSRS show custom gridline

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

[image: Red lines need to be displayed]

Hi

Below is my chart, I need to siaplay a line after each 4 bars. SSRS provide me facility to display lines between the bars, but I want to show the lines between two intervals.

So gray lines are what which can be displayed by "Show Major Gridline" but I need the lines which I highlited in Red, so Red straight lines need to be dsplayed after every month.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since SSRS is not very flexible and sometimes we need to do something tricky to do what we need to do.

Since the X-Axis is monthly data so I double the rows with 15th of each month.

`INSERT INTO @Output
SELECT * FROM Result
UNION ALL
SELECT Cast(Year(DateAdd(d, -15, RevisedPeriod)) AS VarChar(4)) + '-' + Cast(Month(DateAdd(d, -15, RevisedPeriod)) AS VarChar(2)) + '-15', NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL , NULL
FROM Result`

Then I calculate the peak value around all the bars.

`SELECT @Max1 = Max(Bar1) FROM @Output
SELECT @Max2 = Max(Bar2) FROM @Output
SELECT @Max3 = Max(Bar3) FROM @Output
SELECT @Max4 = Max(Bar4) FROM @Output`

`SELECT @MaxAll = Max(Value)
FROM (VALUES (@Max1), (@Max2), (@Max3), (@Max4)) AS AllValues(Value)`

And then get the next peak value that the bar can reach, for example if I get the maximum value as 37,295 then the peak value would be 40,000 - 0.01 so that the line will reach till the top of the chart. Please see following result.

`SET @MaxAll = Cast(Cast(Cast(SubString(Cast(Cast(@MaxAll AS BigInt) AS VarChar(50)), 1, 1) AS Int) + 1 AS VarChar(1)) + Replace(Space(Len(Cast(Cast(@MaxAll AS BigInt) AS VarChar(50)))-1), ' ', '0') AS Decimal(18, 2)) - 0.01`

Finally update the rows representing 15th of each month with this @MaxDAll value

`UPDATE @Output SET PeriodSeparator = @MaxAll WHERE Day(RevisedPeriod) = 15 AND Month(RevisedPeriod) <> 6`

Then in SSRS show this 15th of each month as Range Chart Type (Eror Bar)

This is now showing a line separator between each month.